# How does the buffer from the ws2812b module work?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

This is an example taken from the [ws2812 documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/ws2812/):

```
ws2812.init()
local i, buffer = 0, ws2812.newBuffer(300, 4); buffer:fill(0, 0, 0, 0); tmr.create():alarm(50, 1, function()
  i = i + 1
  buffer:fade(2)
  buffer:set(i % buffer:size() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 255)
  ws2812.write(buffer)
end)
```

First of all I tried to translate this into something more readable and since I use RGB and not RGBW LEDs, I also removed the W component:

```
local numberOfLeds = 300
local bytesPerLed = 3 -- (R, G and B)

ws2812.init()

local i
local buffer = 0

ws2812.newBuffer(numberOfLeds, bytesPerLed)
buffer:fill(255, 255, 255)

tmr.create():alarm(50, 1, function() -- repeat every 50 milliseconds
    i = i + 1
    buffer:fade(2)
    buffer:set(i % buffer:size() + 1, 255, 255, 255)
    ws2812.write(buffer)
end)
```

It doesn't really make any sense to me, though. Why does `buffer` have a fill method? I mean didn't we set it to simply be 0? `buffer = 0`
Am I translating this incorrectly?
The original code said `local i, buffer = 0, ws2812.newBuffer(...); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is equivalent to

```
local i = 0
local buffer = ws2812.newBuffer(300, 4); buffer:fill(0, 0, 0, 0); tmr.create():alarm(50, 1, function()
```

In general,

```
local x,y,z = a,b,c
```

is equivalent to

```
local x = a
local y = b
local z = c
```

See the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.3).

Comment: I see, yes that makes way more sense. Thank you.